# Why does this Java code throw an exception?

Tags: java

I am new with java. I having some exception while running my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int[] num= new int[5];      

        for (int i= 0; 1<num.length; i++)
        {
            num[i]= r.nextInt(100)+1;
            System.out.println(num[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 at Example.main(Example.java:13)

Why am I getting this exception?

Comment: You will need to tell us more.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: `1<num.length` will always be true here. You *probably* meant `i<num.length`.

Comment: You probably want `i<num.length`

Comment: it is giving this "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at Example.main(Example.java:13)"

Comment: You haven't mentioned what your question is, or even what error you are getting. We are not mind-readers, you will have to give us more information than this..

Comment: Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly, you should always copy and paste the exception text, to save us trying to guess which type of exception it is or where it's happening**

You'll be getting an `ArrayOutOfBoundsIndexException`, because the loop is endless yet the index always increments.

```
for (int i= 0; 1<num.length; i++)
```

One is always less than the `length` of `num` so it loops for ever, incrementing `i` each time until `i` is larger than the array size. At which point you'll try to do this

```
num[i] ...
```

And `i` will be out of bounds, throwing the exception.

Comment: Who is down voting all the answers?

Comment: There's always someone that doesn't like that people answer seemingly unclear questions.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the quality of the answers though, seems counter productive.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson But this is not justified ... SO is just an Q&A site

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random r = new Random();
    int[] num = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        num[i] = r.nextInt(100) + 1;
        System.out.println(num[i]);
    }

}
}
```

This is how a loop works:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates. In your case the loop never terminates. That is why you are getting an `ArrayOutOfBoundsIndexException`.